# R syntax meaning using with

Tags: r

Hi Everyone the following two lines of code give me the desired outcome

```
missing=with(pima,glucose==0|diastolic==0|triceps==0|bmi==0)
missing=with(pima,missing<-glucose==0|diastolic==0|triceps==0|bmi==0)
```

However the third line fails

```
missing=with(pima,missing=glucose==0|diastolic==0|triceps==0|bmi==0)
```

Could I get the semantics of each of these lines and an explanation of why the third line fails?

Comment: What do you mean the third line fails?  Does it produce an error? If so,  what is the error message?

Comment: It would help if you give a [mcve]. See [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/4996248) to see what this means for R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look at `?with`; it's seems pretty well explained there. Let's take `mtcars` as an example.

**Case 1**

```
with(mtcars, cyl == 4 | am == 1)
```

Returns a logical vector in your current environment.

**Case 2**

```
with(mtcars, var <- cyl == 4 | am == 1)
```

Returns a logical vector and stores the vector in the local environment constructed from `mtcars`.

From `?with`

> Note that assignments within ‘expr’ take place in the constructed
>        environment and not in the user's workspace.

**Case 3**

```
with(mtcars, var = cyl == 4 | am == 1)
```

`with` tries to evaluate `var = (cyl == 4 | am == 1)` which fails because

```
eval(mtcars$var = mtcars$cyl == 4 | mtcars$am == 1)
```

fails.